# Are there studies on in-app user feedback?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, user-feedback

I'm considering to ask users in app for feedback on a specific feature, right after they used it. The goal is to have a) quantitative feedback on the feature and b) a list of comments from step 3 where I can see what people would like to see improved.

It would be a 4 step process,

1. Non-blocking bottom sheet to ask for feedback
2. Dialog with quantitative question (can be dismissed)
3. Dialog with free-text question ("Why?", can be dismissed)
4. Dialog to ask for data processing consent (GDPR)

[image]

I have seen similar approaches before, for example from Google Lens:

[image]

Are there any publications on how valid this kind of feedback is, and whether it has a negative effect on the user experience?

I find plenty of service providers who make these kinds of in-app dialogs, but so far no solid literature on their usefulness.

Comment: I am not sure about a published paper on this topic, but the general understanding is to have this sort of feedback after the user has become familiar with the app and has accomplished the task for which you would like gather feedback at least once. Also, I think the last screen about GDPR should not be included here as part of the feedback process. Asking user for permission could be part of the login process or contextual.

Comment: Isn't asking for consent in this case highly contextual? As in, you give us information, and we ask that we can use it and connect it to other bits of information (like, how often you've used the feature you're giving feedback on)?

Comment: I found this [article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/exit-intent-good-ux/) from NNg about the Exit intent popups pretty relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to understand is **why** you need this.

If you asking a person who already use this feature you might end up with only positive feedbacks and  the same time you will have people who don’t even know that feature is existed.

If you let people rate their experience from 1 to 5 think about how you will handle this results. What is 4?

If you can not answer this kind of questions for yourself simplify things until you will clearly understand what you are doing and **why**.

Don’t copy practices, do your own thing.